# An internal error occurred during: "Resolving Features for karaf_project" error while creating EIK project

Tags: eclipse, osgi, eclipse-indigo, karaf

I want to create eik project in eclipse with karaf version 3.0.3

I read this tutorial http://karaf.apache.org/manual/eik/latest/user-guide/index.html

I use Eclipse indigo RCP version and Apache Karaf 3.0.3(diffrence is karaf version. Tutorial says 2.3.x but i also try this, same error)

Firstly i install eik repostories. I got this repo from http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/karaf/eik/features/org.apache.karaf.eik.repository/0.9.0/org.apache.karaf.eik.repository-0.9.0.zip and unzip under my C folder. And in Eclipse, Help > Install new software > Add > Local then browse repo file in C. After this, I see 2 selectable option. Select both of them and install.

Secondly,

In eclipse, Select Window > Preferences > OSGI Frameworks steps. And switch perspective with Select Window > Open Perspective > Other > Select Apache Karaf.

In conclusion,

After these settings, i want an eik project. select new > Karaf project. i wrote a project name and next. Select karaf 3.0.3 project. When i click the next button, i got this error :

```
An internal error occurred during: "Resolving Features for karaf_project".
URL [mvn:org.apache.karaf.features/standard/3.0.3/xml/features] could not be resolved.
```

Am i missing something?

Comment: best to ask this question at the karaf user mailinglist